# Unable to set symfony project getting error on app.php

Tags: php, symfony

I have setup new project of symfony. `app_dev.php/register` is working good but when i switch to `app.php/register` then getting error

```
Oops! An Error Occurred

The server returned a "404 Not Found".

Something is broken. Please e-mail us at [email] and let us know what you were doing when 
this error occurred. We will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry for any inconvenience caused.
```

i have clear cache also but still getting this error. please give me solution i am in hurry because my project is goes final but now i am stucked here cannot publish it on live server

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you access it over app.php and get that error. you should try to setup debug modus of app.php file.
to do this you alter following line in the file web/app.php

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
```

to

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);
```

this way symfony tells you what the problem is and i guess it has to do with the routing...